# Create index in Ignite table when save dataframe from pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, ignite

I save Spark dataframe to Apache Ignite table with this code:

```
df.write\
.format("ignite")\
.option("table","REPORT")\
.option("primaryKeyFields", ', '.join(map(str, df.schema.names[:-1])))\
.option("config",configFile)\
.option("compression", "gzip")\
.mode("overwrite")\
.save()
```

But, I cannot find how create index on field with this owerwrite-saving.

I need this, but on .save() operation:

```
CREATE INDEX REPORT_FIELD_IDX ON PUBLIC.REPORT (FIELD)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple to do using the syntax like next:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS AGE_IDX ON "PUBLIC".Person (AGE)
```

In case if a new table wasn't created then **IF NOT EXISTS** will work and nothing will be done. Otherwise, the index will be created.

It can be run using any SQL tool that can be used with Ignite (webconsole, visor, sqlline, jdbc, odbc, etc) but I guess that you are going to do it from Spark job. So you can try to use IgniteSparkSession or IgniteRDD to run SQL over Ignite:

```
IgniteSparkSession igniteSession = IgniteSparkSession.builder()
                .appName("Spark Ignite example")
                .igniteConfig(configPath)
                .getOrCreate();

igniteSession.sqlContext().sql("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS AGE_IDX ON \"PUBLIC\".Person (AGE)");
```

or

```
val cacheRdd = igniteContext.fromCache("partitioned")

val result = cacheRdd.sql(
  "CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS AGE_IDX ON \"PUBLIC\".Person (AGE)")
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that when saving DataFrame with Spark. Creating a table and creating an index are 2 different operations.

[Here](https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/ignite-data-frame#section-ignite-dataframe-options) are all the options for DataFrame saving into Ignite, and as you can see, there is no option for index creation.

Comment: Sorry, but CREATE and INSERT it different operation too. And we use it together with save(OVERWRITE) abstraction.